# association for join through a third table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `A` model, `B` model and `Connecting` model.

A and B have a `con_id` column which is the id in Connecting model.

I tried to do the following:
In A:

```
has_many :connectings
has_many : bs, :through => connectings
```

In B:

```
has_many :connectings
has_many :as, :through => connectings
```

Then in Connecting:

```
belongs_to :as
belongs_to :bs
```

Then trying to make a joins and includes query:

```
A.joins(:bs).includes(:connectings).where("my_condition")
```

It fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your `Connecting` model make it singular.   `belongs_to :a  # foreign key - a_id`
  `belongs_to :b     # foreign key - b_id`. Also, if this is your actual code there is a space between `:` and `bs` in the A model.  Here is a reference from some [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment at the start of the question I'm guessing your models and migrations are setup incorrectly. The `A` and `B` models and tables shouldn't have a `con_id` column. The foreign keys should be in the joining table.

Your models should look like this:

```
class Connecting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a  # foreign key - a_id
  belongs_to :b # foreign key - b_id
end
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connectings
  has_many :bs, through: :connectings
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connectings
  has_many :bs, through: :connectings
end
```

I'd remove your models and rollback your migrations and redo them. Here are the [rails guides for has_many :through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to guide you through the setup.

A basic migration, adopted from the rails guides, would look something like this:

```
# Hope the tables and models have better names, 'as' might cause issues.    
class CreateConnectings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :as do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :bs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :connectings do |t|
      t.belongs_to :a, index: true
      t.belongs_to :b, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```